# Real and imaginary part of

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find the real and imaginary part of $$f(z)=(−3y^2+6ixy+3x^2)e^{2(iy+x)}$$

I came up with: \begin{align}Re &= e^{2x}(-3y^2\cos(y)-6xy\sin(y)+3x^2\cos(y))\\Im&= ie^{2x}(-3y^2\sin(y)+6xy\cos(y)+3x\sin(y))\end{align}

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to know if the answer is correct or do you know it is wrong and want to know why? If it is the former, then wolframalpha.com is your friend. Otherwise please explain what you want to know

Comment: Recall that for $z=x+iy$ the real and imaginary part are real numbers, therefore you need to eliminate the "i" fro "Im". There is also a typo in the last x term (it should be $x^2$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can use that

$$e^{2(iy+x)}=e^{2x}(\cos(2y)+i\sin(2y))$$

and therefore

$$\Re (f(z))=(-3y^2+3x^2)e^{2x}\cos(2y)-6xye^{2x}\sin(2y)$$

$$\Im (f(z))=6xye^{2x}\cos(2y)+(-3y^2+3x^2)e^{2x}\sin(2y)$$

Recall that real part and imaginary parts are real numbers.